# disable back button in react-router 2

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router

I am using react-router 2. My routes are defined as

```
   <Route path="/" component={App}>
       <IndexRoute component={Home}/>
       <Route path="/about" component={About}/>
       <Route path="/login" component={Login} onEnter={redirectToDashboard}/>
       <Route path="/logout" component={Logout} onEnter={logoutSession}/>
       <Route path="/dashboard" component={Dashboard} onEnter={redirectToLogin}/>
   </Route>
```

Everything working fine but I am having problem disabling back button from my dashboard page.

After successful login I am redirecting user to dashboard page but when user clicks back button it goes to login page again. I want to disable back button of `browser` when user is on dashboard page.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Your best bet, is when the user is login he/ she is redirected to dashbaord. if for some reason the user click on back button you should:

if the user is logged in
 stay on the page dashboard

```
if(logged) {
  history.pushState(null, null, location.href);
  window.onpopstate = function(event) {
    history.go(1);
  };
}
```

it will be not possible to go back.

Comment: currently, this disables the back button for all routes. How do I, for instance, get back button to work when I  route from the dashboard to another page and click on the back button? how do I go back to the dashboard with the back button?

Answer (score 9):

Applying all these hacks the URL changes to `login` for a moment and then to `wherever-we-push`.
Instead, what we can do is: In login, where api endpoint returns success, do:

```
history.replace('/Whatever_screen')
```

This will remove login screen from `window.history` stack, and the screen will not flicker.

Comment: Could you format your answer better and try reorangize it?

Comment: This should have been accepted as the correct answer.

Answer (score 6):

On your page which you want to disable back (example, on LoginApp ) add this block, to disable web history back

```
componentDidMount() {
    window.history.pushState(null, document.title, window.location.href);
    window.addEventListener('popstate', function (event){
        window.history.pushState(null, document.title,  window.location.href);
    });
}
```

Comment: this works inside a useEffect Too.. thx

Answer (score 1):

it's not possible to disable browser buttons.
my advice is to redirect user back to dashboard page if he/she is logged

Answer (score 1):

Actually you can't disable *back* button. You can use a hack by preventing browser's "*back*" action. Just add to your `Dashboard` component `compnentWillMount()` lifecycle method some code that will trigger browser's "*forward*" action:

```
componentWillMount() {
   setTimeout(() => {
     window.history.forward()
   }, 0)
   window.onunload=function(){null};
}
```

But most probably a better solution would be some redirection based on users logged state.

Answer (score 1):

in your login screen add replace to /dashboard

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { withRouter } from 'react-router-dom'
import createBrowserHistory from 'history/createBrowserHistory'
const history = createBrowserHistory()

class LoginPage extends Component {
    componentDidMount(){
        history.replace({ pathname: '/dashboard' })
    }
    render() {
        const { history } = this.props
        return (
            <div>
            <h1>Login Page</h1>
            <button onClick={() => {
              login().then(() => {
                history.push('/dashboard')
              })
            }}>Login</button>
          </div>
        );
    }
}

export default withRouter(LoginPage);
```

The reason is replace your current path (/login) to /dashboard. Before adding this, please make sure you setup your authentication correctly.

Comment: This is the best answer. `history.replace(...)` replaces the current view with a new view, by hitting the back button you go back to the view before that. [History Doc](https://github.com/ReactTraining/history/blob/master/docs/api-reference.md#history.replace)

Answer (score 1):

In order to improve the code reusability, we can add an event listener in our `index.html` and dispatch the browser back disable event from all of our `componentDidMount()` methods.

In the `index.html`,

```
window.addEventListener('navigationhandler', function (e) {
  window.history.pushState(null, document.title, window.location.href);
  window.addEventListener('popstate', function (event) {
    window.history.pushState(null, document.title, window.location.href);
  });
});
```

In React `componentDidMount()` method,

```
componentDidMount() {
   window.dispatchEvent(new CustomEvent("navigationhandler"));
}
```

Comment: Currently, this disables the back button for all routes. How do I, for instance, get back button to work when I  route from the dashboard to another page and click on the back button? how do I go back to the dashboard with the back button?

Comment: You can manually handle a back button or get the state of current page and store to variable when user try to go back try to check the value and proceed accordingly, otherwise if you want to override the current back button function, do not call the window.dispatchevent method instead you can write push state method

Comment: I will really appreciate it if you could please replicate with an example to a codepen or a sandbox. Thanks.

Comment: Sure I'll provide you the sample.

Comment: Can you ask a question and tag me there so I can answer the community can also get use of it

Comment: Sure I'll do that.

Answer (score 1):

It's not possible to disable browser buttons. But we can use history methods like `listen()`, `go()` and `push()` to override the default behaviour of back button in react.js. Also try to use `withRouter()`.

The following is the sample code for doing this. Please look into `componentDidMount()` and `componenetDidUnmount()` methods.

```
import React from "react";
import { Redirect, Switch, Route, withRouter } from "react-router";

import Page1 from "./Page1";
import Page2 from "./Page2";
import Page3 from "./Page3";

class App extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    // Store the previous pathname and search strings
    this.currentPathname = null;
    this.currentSearch = null;
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    const { history } = this.props;

    history.listen((newLocation, action) => {
      if (action === "PUSH") {
        if (
          newLocation.pathname !== this.currentPathname ||
          newLocation.search !== this.currentSearch
        ) {
          this.currentPathname = newLocation.pathname;
          this.currentSearch = newLocation.search;

          history.push({
            pathname: newLocation.pathname,
            search: newLocation.search
          });
        }
      } else {
        history.go(1);
      }
    });
  }

  componentWillUnmount() {
    window.onpopstate = null;
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <Switch>
        <Route exact path="/" render={() => <Redirect to="/page1" />} />
        <Route path="/page1" component={Page1} />
        <Route path="/page2" component={Page2} />
        <Route path="/page3" component={Page3} />
      </Switch>
    );
  }
}

export default withRouter(App);
```

For more: [Disable react back button](https://github.com/codemaker2015/react-disable-back-button)

Comment: I found the `history.listen()` very helpful here -- nice solution!

Answer (score 1):

- Simple and Sweet.
- No need to mess with history stack.
- solution even does not depend on react router.
- It will even prevent the current component from unmounting when back button is clicked, hence it also preserves state of the app as well.

```
// prevent back
useEffect(() => {
    window.addEventListener('popstate', (e) => {
      window.history.go(1);
    });
  }, []);
```

Comment: where do you add this code?

Comment: Inside the page where you want prevent going back in history after back button of browser is clicked.