# How to disable browser back button only for a specific component

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I have 3 components : 
Login
Dashboard
Workspace

once the user successfully logged in, he will be navigated to Dashboard. From the dashboard, he gets to navigate to the workspace.
 **condition:** *1.once logged in navigated to dashboard user should be able to go back to the login page on click on browser backward button. 2. But he can navigate backward from workspace to dashboard*.

[I have referred to this question to solve my problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36141470/disable-back-button-in-react-router-2)

**Problem:** condition 2 is not achieved. once I navigate from dashboard to workspace I'm not able to navigate back to the dashboard by clicking the browser back button.

Login code

```
login(newUser).then(res => { 

                if(res === "NULL")                        
                {
                    this.setState({confirmPswdShow: true});
                }else if(res === "wrongPassword")          
                {
                    const password ="password invalid";
                    this.setState({authPassword : password});
                }else{                                       
                   window.history.pushState(null, null, window.location.href);
                    window.onpopstate = function(event) {
                        window.history.go(1);
                    };              
                    this.props.history.push("/Dashboard");
                }
            })
```

dashboard code

```
openProjectCreate(details){
        console.log(details);
        openProject(details)
        .then(res => {
            console.log(res);
            this.props.history.push("/WorkSpace");
        })
    }
```

Comment: you navigate to dashboard, then click something to navigate to workspace and then it doesn't work to click the back button to go back to dashboard? can you show us some code?

Comment: ys sure...I will add the code

Comment: yes.....From the workspace, I should be able to navigate back to dashboard with the help of browser back button

Comment: Why do you add this? window.onpopstate = function(event) {
                        window.history.go(1);
                    };

Comment: so that the previous page does not appear on click of browser bakward button

Comment: you shouldn't do that because it will disable the back button for all pages.

Answer (score 0):

You should not overwrite the pop functionality on window. To disable the back to login just replace it's URL in history:

```js
login(newUser).then(res => {
    if (res === "NULL") {
        this.setState({
            confirmPswdShow: true
        });
    } else if (res === "wrongPassword") {
        const password = "password invalid";
        this.setState({
            authPassword: password
        });
    } else {
        this.props.history.replace({
            pathname: '/Dashboard'
        });
        this.props.history.push("/Dashboard");
    }
})
```