# How to block user's click on back button of brower using react

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, react-router-dom

I have an app, and whenever users click on the back button I want ask: "You may have some unsaved changed. Are you sure to go back?".
How can I achieve this react?
Can I use react router dom for that? or is there any other method?

Comment: Does this help? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25806608/how-to-detect-browser-back-button-event-cross-browser

Comment: What versions of `react-router` and `react-router-dom` are you using? From your project's directory run `npm list react-router-react-router-dom` and report back.

Comment: Yes.. i will..its the lastest..maybe 5

Comment: Well, current is v6 which removed any sort of `Prompt` component to block navigation actions, and doesn't directly expose out the `history` object to even do a `history.block`. Version 5 ***does*** however do this. The version you are using is a very relevant and important detail.

Answer (score 0):

Can you try using window.confirm?

```
<button 
  className="btn btn-danger" 
  onClick={() => {if(window.confirm('You may have some unsaved changed. Are you sure to go back?')){
    //Your back button logic
  }}
>
  Back
</button>
```

Comment: Actually i want to block the browser's back button not a custom one in the app

Comment: Can you follow this link? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36141470/disable-back-button-in-react-router-2

Comment: Nop.. none of them works right now